# Intellisense is not working in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2014

Intellisense is not working in Microsoft SQL Server 2014, it was working fine in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 but once I installed 2014 it is not working.

Under `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Transact-SQL -> IntelliSense` it says it is enabled there.

I have also tried refeshing the IntelliSense cache with Ctrl-Shft-R but that doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: There are solutions for that on SuperUser.com.

Comment: are you connecting to static db?

Comment: not sure but it is working in version 2012 installed in colleague's system and not working in mine in version 2014.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with Intellisense. Just hit Ctrl+Shift+R to force SSMS to refresh its cache. Note that *some* dangerous commands like `truncate table` don't allow Intellisense.

Comment: Also note that SSMS is now a separate free product that works across all supported server versions. You can download the latest version (16.5.1) from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx)

Comment: Installed version 17.1 and its working fine.

Comment: I never had much luck with Intellisense and switched to free add-in Apex Complete add-in a while ago. To enable auto-complete after installation, you can hit Ctrl+Shift+A. If you want to customize this feature for your needs, you can do it in Options/General/HintList. You can find some additional tips in this article:
https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-improve-sql-code-layout-and-presentation/

Answer (score 4):

From my personal experience, SSMS IntelliSense is a pure crap, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I'd go for third party tools.

If you're willing to spend your cash, I'd recommend [Redgate SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/).
If you need a free product, try [dbForge SQL Complete](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/), it's not as good as SQL Prompt, but does a decent job.

Answer (score 3):

Perform following steps:

```
Under Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache
```

Restart SSMS.Then try

Comment: Not working, how? Some commands don't allow intellisense, like `truncate table`. Also try `Ctrl+Shift+R to force a reload of the cache. Finally, make sure you download the latest SSMS version from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

After Refreshing local cache, if still not working, then try to delete temporary file of OS. for me it's work,  I hope this will fix your's issue as well.

Comment: It worked for me when I deleted files in %temp% and restarted SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

I am with SQL Server Management Studio 2014 and this working "Just hit Ctrl+Shift+R to force SSMS to refresh its cache." – Panagiotis Kanavos